# Tableview crash when deleting rows in UITableView - Style:plain and section footers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a tableview backed by a fetchedresultscontroller.  When I delete a row that causes the bottom row of a tableview to scroll up so the tv doesn't fill the entire screen, I get the crash below.

**Here are the workarounds I've found**.

1. If I change the tableview to be grouped rather than plain - the error goes away.
2. If I remove the section footers - the error goes away.  This is not a viable workaround for me.

> The error occurs after "controllerWillChangeContent" and prior to the "controllerDidChangeContent" - the code here is just copy/pasted from Apple's FRC protocol reference.

Anyone know why this occurs? Since it works fine with Grouped tableview it seems like it's likely an Apple bug - but I thought I'd ask here first before reporting it.

> **Assertion failure** in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableViewSupport.m:2661
> 2014-03-08 17:13:29.226 workbox[7527:70b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction with userInfo (null)

[Sample program](https://github.com/workboxsoftware/IOS-TableView-Bug)

Comment: Can you post a part of your code?

Comment: Here's a sample program:https://github.com/workboxsoftware/IOS-TableView-Bug

Comment: Have you filed a bug report to Apple?

Comment: I have the same issue - crashing when there's a footer and it goes away when it's removed.

Comment: Yes - I submitted this to Apple including the sample program.  And yes, I know the bug goes away when the footer is removed - but that was not a viable option for me - I have totals on the footer line.  I ended up making it a Grouped table which is unfortunate because the Plain style has that nice feature of keeping the heading and footer fixed - which in my case lets a user see totals while scrolling through a large section.

Comment: Try to look to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893712/uitableview-crash-when-adding-a-section-footer-view-in-empty-section) and accepted answer, there could be really problem with section footer.

Comment: This may help you out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744680/assertion-failure-when-i-use-the-add-function

Answer (score 0):

I have download your project on github, tested on a iPad Air.
I have clicked on some elements and even when the app should scroll up because you have many elements, no problems/crash at all

I have tested on a xCode 7.3.2 and iPad Air 9.2. simulator

Could you please, say with wich device it's crash?