# CoreData: error: Serious application error while using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios7, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController with UICollectionView. Whenever I get a call from the server I update the Core data table and from using core data notification I update the UICollectionView. When I do this, I'm getting an error like this,

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section
>   after the update (12) must be equal to the number of items contained
>   in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of
>   items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted)
>   and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that
>   section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

From this thread [Assertion failure when i use the Add Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744680/assertion-failure-when-i-use-the-add-function)

I understand that my Collectionview is being updated when it is undergoing updation. My question is, How can I prevent this scenario?

my code:

> - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
>     @synchronized(self)
>     {
>         if (controller == myFetchedResultsController)
>         {
>             if ([self.sectionChangesInCollectionView count] > 0)
>             {
>                 [self.myCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
>
>   ```
>               for (NSDictionary *change in self.sectionChangesInCollectionView)
>               {
>                   [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
>   ```
>
>   {
>
>   ```
>                       NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
>                       switch (type)
>                       {
>                           case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
>                               [self.myCollectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj
>   ```
>
>   unsignedIntegerValue]]];
>                                     break;
>                                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
>                                     [self.myCollectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj
>     unsignedIntegerValue]]];
>                                     break;
>                                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
>                                     [self.myCollectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj
>     unsignedIntegerValue]]];
>                                     break;
>                             }
>                         }];
>                     }
>                 } completion:nil];
>             }
>
>   ```
>       if ([self.objectChangesInCollectioView count] > 0 && [self.sectionChangesInCollectionView count] == 0)
>       {
>
>           if ([self shouldReloadCollectionViewToPreventKnownIssue] ||
>   ```
>
>   self.myCollectionView.window == nil) {
>                     // This is to prevent a bug in UICollectionView from occurring.
>                     // The bug presents itself when inserting the first object or deleting the last object in a collection view.
>                     // [UICollectionView Assertion failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611292/uicollectionview-assertion-failure)
>                     // This code should be removed once the bug has been fixed, it is tracked in OpenRadar
>                     // http://openradar.appspot.com/12954582
>                     [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
>
>   ```
>           }
>           else
>           {
>
>
>               [self.myCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
>
>                   for (NSDictionary *change in self.objectChangesInCollectioView)
>                   {
>                       [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
>   ```
>
>   {
>
>   ```
>                           NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
>                           switch (type)
>                           {
>                               case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
>                               {
>                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
>                                                  {
>                                                      [self.myCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
>                                                  });
>                                   break;
>                               }
>                               case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
>                               {
>                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
>                                                  {
>                                                      [self.myCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
>                                                  });
>                                   break;
>                               }
>                               case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
>                               {
>                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
>                                                  {
>                                                      [self.myCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
>                                                  });
>                                   break;
>                               }
>                               case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
>                               {
>                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
>                                                  {
>                                                      [self.myCollectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:obj[0]
>   ```
>
>   toIndexPath:obj[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744680/assertion-failure-when-i-use-the-add-function)];
>                                                        });
>                                         break;
>                                     }
>                                 }
>                             }];
>                         }
>                     } completion:nil];
>                 }
>             }
>
>   ```
>       [self.sectionChangesInCollectionView removeAllObjects];
>       [self.objectChangesInCollectioView removeAllObjects];
>   }
>   else
>   {
>
>   }
>   ```
>
>   } }
>
> ## pragma mark - collectionView bug fix method
>
> - (BOOL)shouldReloadCollectionViewToPreventKnownIssue 
>     {
>     __block BOOL shouldReload = NO;
>
>   for (NSDictionary *change in self.objectChangesInCollectioView) {
>         [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
>             NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
>             NSIndexPath *indexPath = obj;
>             switch (type) {
>                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
>                     if ([self.myCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section] == 0) {
>                         shouldReload = YES;
>                     } else {
>                         shouldReload = NO;
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
>                     if ([self.myCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section] == 1) {
>                         shouldReload = YES;
>                     } else {
>                         shouldReload = NO;
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
>                     shouldReload = NO;
>                     break;
>                 case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
>                     shouldReload = NO;
>                     break;
>             }
>         }];
>     }
>
>   return shouldReload; }

Answer (score 0):

Delete the core data item and let the delegate callbacks take care of deleting the table view row. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27769837/1673045) answer.